# awk way to add numbers in line fields

Tags: text-processing, awk, numeric-data

**data.now:**

```
blah1,dah,blaha,sweet,games.log,5297484456,nagios-toin,529748456,on__host=92 SERVICE__ALERT_=51 Warning___The__results__of__service=16 Warning___on__host=92 Auto_save__of__retention__data__completed=1 Warning___Return=68 PASSIVE__SERVICE__CHECK_=53 ,1026--1313,1
blah1,dah,blaha,sweet,games.log,5297484456,nagios-toin,529748456,on__host=14 SERVICE__ALERT_=51 Warning___The__results__of__service=16 Warning___on__host=93 Auto_save__of__retention__data__completed=1 Warning___Return=68 PASSIVE__SERVICE__CHECK_=53 ,1026--1313,1
blah1,dah,blaha,sweet,games.log,5297484456,nagios-toin,529748456,on__host=93 SERVICE__ALERT_=51 Warning___The__results__of__service=16 Warning___on__host=92 Auto_save__of__retention__data__completed=1 Warning___Return=8 PASSIVE__SERVICE__CHECK_=53 ,1026--1313,1
blah1,dah,blaha,sweet,games.log,5297484456,nagios-toin,529748456,on__host=73 SERVICE__ALERT_=51 Warning___The__results__of__service=16 Warning___on__host=99 Auto_save__of__retention__data__completed=1 Warning___Return=68 PASSIVE__SERVICE__CHECK_=53 ,1026--1313,1
blah1,dah,blaha,sweet,games.log,5297484456,nagios-toin,529748456,on__host=93 SERVICE__ALERT_=51 Warning___The__results__of__service=16 Warning___on__host=75 Auto_save__of__retention__data__completed=1 Warning___Return=38 PASSIVE__SERVICE__CHECK_=53 ,1026--1313,1
blah1,dah,blaha,sweet,games.log,5297484456,nagios-toin,529748456,on__host=21 SERVICE__ALERT_=51 Warning___The__results__of__service=16 Warning___on__host=12 Auto_save__of__retention__data__completed=1 Warning___Return=28 PASSIVE__SERVICE__CHECK_=23 ,1026--1313,1[/CODE]
```

The fields in each line above are separated by "comma".  What I'm interested in is field 9.

Field 9 has a number of values.

**What i want to do is two parts:**

1. Be able to add up all the values of a **specific pattern** in all the lines in the datafile.  For instance, if i want to know the total value "on__host" on all lines in the data file.
2. Be able to add up all the values from all the patterns on each line, on all the lines in the log.

There was an old data i was working with which only had a single value in the 9th field. that was easy to handle.  The data looked like this:

**data.prev**

```
blah1,dah,blaha,sweet,games.log,5297484456,nagios-toin,529748456,53,1026--1313,1
```

And all I needed to do to add up the values in the 9th field of all the lines was:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{sum=0} {sum+=$9} END {print sum}' data.prev
```

The kind of script that would solve this problem for me would look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
Pattern=$1
if [ "${Pattern}" = "allpatterns" ] ; then
   awk should add up all the values in the 9th field of data in data.now
else
   if the user did not specify "allpatterns", then, awk should take the pattern name specified by the user and use that to decide which pattern to add up in the 9th field of all the lines.
    awk -F"," '$9 ~ /'${Pattern}'/ '{do awk magic}'  -- this is just an idea.
fi
```

this script is expected to run on all unix systems. The shell i will be using is either /bin/sh or /bin/bash.

For the first part of my request, if all the values of all the patterns on all the lines in the data file are added up, the output should be just the resulting sum of the numbers..i.e 504 (just an arbitrary number i picked).

For the second part of my request, if the values of a specific pattern are added up, the output should be just the resulting sum of the values for that specific pattern...i.e. "on__host=400".

Answer (score 1):

That's the kind of thing that is easier done with `perl` (not that there are many things that are easier done in `awk` than `perl`):

```
$ perl -F, -lae '$c{$1} += $2 while $F[8] =~ /(\S+)=(\d+)/g;
                 END {print "$_ => $c{$_}" for sort keys %c}' < file
Auto_save__of__retention__data__completed => 6
PASSIVE__SERVICE__CHECK_ => 288
SERVICE__ALERT_ => 306
Warning___Return => 278
Warning___The__results__of__service => 96
Warning___on__host => 463
on__host => 386
```

Change the `END` block to `{print $c{on__host}}` if you only want the value for `on__host` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, I think something like this would work:

```
cat data.now | awk -F, '{print $9}' | sed 's/=/ /g' | awk '
    { 
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i += 2) {
            a[$i]+=$(i+1); 
        }
    } 
    END {
        for (i in a) print i, "=", a[i]
    }'
```

This code produces the following output:

```
PASSIVE__SERVICE__CHECK_ = 288
Warning___Return = 278
Auto_save__of__retention__data__completed = 6
SERVICE__ALERT_ = 306
Warning___The__results__of__service = 96
on__host = 386
Warning___on__host = 463
```

The only potential problem here is that the order is not the same as the one of the original file. If the order matters to you, you can use:

```
cat data.now | awk -F, '{print $9}' | sed 's/=/ /g' | awk '
    { 
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i += 2) {
            a[$i]+=$(i+1); 
            b[i]=$i;
        }
    } 
    END {
        for (i in b) print b[i], "=", a[b[i]]
    }'
```

but it's not as easy to read.

For your second question, I think that this works to calculate the sum, although it might not be the shortest or most efficient way to do it.

```
cat data.now | awk -F, '{print $9}' | 
    sed "s/.*\<${Pattern}=\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/g" | 
    awk '{s += $1} END {print s}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `split` filed `$9` on space, then iterate over the result to select the pattern, and `split` the found element on `=` to extract the value:

```
awk -F, -v pat='^on__host=' '{
  n = split($9,a," "); 
  for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
    if(a[i] ~ pat) {
      split(a[i],b,"="); 
      sum+=b[2]
    } 
  }
} 
END{print sum}
' data.now
```